# Sick TIM571 is transmitting too few datas

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, laserscanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working with the Sick TIM571 Lidar with ROS-Kinetic on Ubuntu and I'm using the Sick-Tim-ROS-Package.
The connection via ethernet works fine and I'm getting distance-datas from the Lidar.

The TIM571 has an angular resolution  of 0.333° with an opening angle of 270°. So the lidar should deliver 810 distances.
The problem is, that I'm only getting 270 distances from the lidar.

In the Sopas Tool on Windows the angular resolution is set so 0.333° and I can't change that.

I would be very pleased if someone could help me with that Issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286228/sick-tim571-is-transmitting-too-few-datas/) by [Tobias36](https://answers.ros.org/users/34268/tobias36/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mallain](https://answers.ros.org/users/32116/mallain/) on 2019-08-27**:
I am experiencing the same issue with both the older `sick_tim` package and the newer SICK AG supported `sick_scan` driver package.

Please see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_scan/issues/48).

**Update:** see my post below for resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I experienced the same issue with the default configuration on a SICK TiM571, and discovered that I had the `median filter` option enabled in SOPAS. After disabling this feature and permanently saving to the device, I am now receiving full (0.333 deg) resolution samples from the `sick_scan` driver.

Credit to SICK support for helping me find diagnose and solve this.

Mitchell

---

Originally posted by [mallain](https://answers.ros.org/users/32116/mallain/) with karma: 16 on 2019-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0